# Class with recursive method using int vector element as input

Tags: c++, class, recursion, vector

I'm trying to make a class that have a recursive binary operator taking the input from a vector but for some reason I keep having these error:

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
In member function 'int ReduceGeneric::reduce(std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>::iterator)':|
|14|error: no matching function for call to 'ReduceGeneric::binaryOperator(std::vector<int>::iterator, int&)'|
|14|note: candidate is:|
|8|note: virtual int ReduceGeneric::binaryOperator(int, int)|
|8|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}' to 'int'|
|16|error: invalid cast to abstract class type 'ReduceGeneric'|
|4|note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'ReduceGeneric':|
|8|note:     virtual int ReduceGeneric::binaryOperator(int, int)|
|22|error: invalid cast to abstract class type 'ReduceGeneric'|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class ReduceGeneric {
public:
    int reduce(std::vector<int>& v, std::vector<int>::iterator i); //set i=v.begin() in main
private:
    virtual int binaryOperator(int m, int n) =0;
    int result;
};

int ReduceGeneric::reduce(std::vector<int>& v, std::vector<int>::iterator i)   {
    if (i==v.begin())   {
        result=binaryOperator(v.begin(),*i);
        i++;
        return ReduceGeneric(v,i);
    } else if (i==v.end()) {
        return result;
    }   else    {
        result=binaryOperator(result,*i);
        i++;
        return ReduceGeneric(v,i);
    }
}

class ReduceMinimum : public ReduceGeneric  {
private:
    int binaryOperator(int m, int n);
};

int ReduceMinimum::binaryOperator(int i, int j) {
    if (i<=j)   {
        return i;
    }   else    {
        return j;
    }
}
```

Thanks a bunch. I'm new to programming so any input is a good input. And apparently, my post is full of code so I'm trying to add more text. I love pizza.

Comment: Like the error says, you are trying to assign an iterator to an int parameter. v.begin() is an iterator. You can use front() or access the iterator with *

Answer (score 0):

You need to change these lines for a successful build:

```
result=binaryOperator(v.begin(),*i);
```

to

```
result=binaryOperator(*v.begin(),*i);
```

as @o_weisman had mentioned.

both lines of:

```
return ReduceGeneric(v,i);
```

to

```
return ReduceGeneric::reduce(v,i);
```

as you need to call function not class.